# hamlpy для django

Tags: django, шаблоны, haml

Хочу прикрутить [hamlpy](https://github.com/jessemiller/HamlPy) к django. Добавил его в APPS и TEMPLATE_LOADERS (согласно инструкциям)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.sites',                                                     ##

    'hamlpy',
    'testapp',
]


TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (

    'hamlpy.template.loaders.HamlPyFilesystemLoader',
    'hamlpy.template.loaders.HamlPyAppDirectoriesLoader',

    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
##        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'loaders': TEMPLATE_LOADERS,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Использую view:

```
haml =  lambda request: render(request,"article.haml",{})
```

И шаблон:

```
#profile
    .left.column
        #date 2010/02/18
        #address Toronto, ON
    .right.column
        #bio Jesse Miller {{user}}
```

Но на выходе получаю обычный рендеринг джанго-шаблона:

```
#profile .left.column #date 2010/02/18 #address Toronto, ON .right.column #bio Jesse Miller AnonymousUser
```

Пробовал так же другие пакеты: [django-hamlpy](https://github.com/nyaruka/django-hamlpy) и [shpaml](https://github.com/Rootbuzz/shpaml), но получаю такой же результат. Второй день штурмую, не могу одолеть. Прошу помощи

Comment: hamlpy и shpaml явно устарели и с современными версиями Django работать не будут, а что у вас не получилось с django-hamlpy, непонятно

Comment: @andreymal, почти разобрался. Оказывается предпоследним коммитом django-hamlpy прекратили поддержку python2, а у меня именно он